# Proble with not recognizing the wifi connection

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, wifi-hardware-switch

I have changed my macbook pro operating system to Ubuntu Linux last night. That night the wifi network was recognized but this morning it does not recognizing wifi network at all .
Please help.
here is what I got running Terminal:

```
ebmo@ebmo-MacBookPro:~$ nmcli
enp1s0f0: unavailable
        "Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe"
        ethernet (tg3), 40:6C:8F:52:D5:50, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
"nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(5) manual pages for complete usage details.
ebmo@ebmo-MacBookPro:~$ nmcli connection show
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
ENNN                2ee7e18c-80cf-4ea5-8eff-df6343119437  wifi      --     
HUAWEI P20 Pro      d39ea4a1-6a84-4bc2-9693-17b4eed1dc5d  wifi      --     
Wired connection 1  f61c19a7-d0f2-3270-886b-7673319531df  ethernet  --     
ebmo@ebmo-MacBookPro:~$ lshw-c network
lshw-c: command not found
ebmo@ebmo-MacBookPro:~$ lshw -c
Hardware Lister (lshw) - B.02.18
usage: lshw [-format] [-options ...]
       lshw -version

    -version        print program version (B.02.18)

format can be
    -html           output hardware tree as HTML
    -xml            output hardware tree as XML
    -json           output hardware tree as a JSON object
    -short          output hardware paths
    -businfo        output bus information

options can be
    -class CLASS    only show a certain class of hardware
    -C CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -c CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -disable TEST   disable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -enable TEST    enable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -quiet          don't display status
    -sanitize       sanitize output (remove sensitive information like serial numbers, etc.)
    -numeric        output numeric IDs (for PCI, USB, etc.)
    -notime         exclude volatile attributes (timestamps) from output

ebmo@ebmo-MacBookPro:~$ lshw -c network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0f0
       version: 10
       serial: 40:6c:8f:52:d5:50
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=57765-v1.37 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:a0400000-a040ffff memory:a0410000-a041ffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a0600000-a0603fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
ebmo@ebmo-MacBookPro:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
ebmo@ebmo-MacBookPro:~$
```

Comment: Your Broadcom wireless needs a driver to work properly. Please check the duplicate. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.